# TFastLineSeries class not found error in TeeChart Standard 2014 RAD XE5?

Tags: teechart, c++builder-xe5

We are using TFastlineSeries from TeeChart VCL. The program compiles without any error. However, when we execute the project, 'class TFastLineSeries not found' messagebox is displayed.

We are using Embarcadero C++Builder XE5 and TeeChart Standard 2014 RAD XE5.
A similar issue had occurred in TeeChart for XE4 and Steema Software released a work around. When I search their site and elsewhere, I don't find this issue in XE5.

Can someone tell me what could be wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided a simple example project we can run as-is to reproduce the problem here. The XE4 patch you mention is available at the bottom of this page:http://www.steema.com/download/vcl. You can upgrade it for XE5.

Comment: The application is a legacy application. Carving a sample to demonstrate what is going on may be slightly difficult. We have the XE5 C++ Builder edition and the XE Workaround uses the Delphi. Is there a XE5 fix for this issue?

Comment: The link I provided includes both, Delphi and C++ Builder workarounds, the later being: http://www.steema.com/files/public/teechart/vcl/XE4_BCB_Workaround_VCL_FastLineSeries.zip

Comment: The code snippets are below: __fastcall TCustomChart::TCustomChart(TComponent* Owner)
  : TChart(Owner)
{
   RealTimeSeries = new TFastLineSeries(this);
   FileViewSeries = new TLineSeries(this);

   RealTimeSeries->ParentChart = this;
   FileViewSeries->ParentChart = this;
}
DFM:
object RTchart0: TCustomChart
 object TFastLineSeries
          LinePen.Color = 10708548
          XValues.Name = 'X'
          XValues.Order = loAscending
          YValues.Name = 'Y'
          YValues.Order = loNone
    end
end

Comment: You can either try upgrading the XE4 workaround to XE5 or what's suggested here: http://www.teechart.net/support/viewtopic.php?t=1736&highlight=class+tfastlineseries

Comment: Thanks for the Link. This is what we used XE4. I can't build it in C++ builder neither I can include this as it depends on older version of rtl

Comment: The support site suggests adding TeeEditPro. Can you please let me know how would I do this? I am new to C++ Builder (and TeeChart) and we have only the TeeChart Standard with XE5. Is there a way to call RegisterSeries()? When this problem occurs, the Form is blank in Design view. So, I am not sure how to go about it. Your inputs are appreciated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87981/discussion-between-deepakh-and-narcis-calvet).

Answer (score 2):

I've rebuilt the fix with XE5 and the TeeChart Lite version shipped with the IDE.
The zip [here](http://www.steema.com/files/public/teechart/vcl/XE5_BCB_Workaround_VCL_FastLineSeries.zip) includes the compiled package and the headers for C++.

Note there's also a free update for the TeeChart Lite version shipped with XE5 [here](http://cc.embarcadero.com/item/29708).

Comment: Thanks a lot for providing prompt response and the hotfix. There seems to be another error now. When I build, the tool prompts for the path of Tee.lib with an error message 'Unable to find static library Tee.lib". If I cancel this prompt, the linker fails with an error message 'Unable to open file TEE.LIB'. This happened after the hotfix package was installed. Can someone suggest possible reasons for this? I have used TFastLineSeries inside a custom control (built and loaded as separate BPL) and used the custom control in the main application. Any suggestions?

Comment: When FastLineSeries workaround is added, TEE.LIB is automatically added to the build command. To resolve this, I copied the Tee919.lib to Tee.lib and the linker error goes. However, when executed, TLineSeries Not found error message is displayed. Is this a similar issue as missing TFastLineSeries? If so, would it be possible to provide a fix for this?

Comment: It works fine for me in a new and simple C++Builder project. Does it for you? If so, please try to arrange a simple example project we can run as-is to reproduce the problem

Comment: Would it be possible to provide this simple C++ Builder project? I can follow the same structure and test it.

Comment: Note there's a free update for the Lite version included with XE5. I've edited the answer. If you still find problems with it, I'll prepare that simple project.

Comment: We are using the Standard Version: TeeChart Standard 2014 for RAD XE5

Comment: I would highly appreciate if the sample C++ project can be made available for TeeChart Standard 2014 for RAD XE5 that uses TFastLineSeries and TLineSeries.

Comment: Find it [here](http://www.teechart.net/files/public/support/Line+FastLine_BCBXE5.zip)